# Array available in nested functions, but not on the same level?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am facing this weird issue where the content of my array variable is available in nested functions, but not on the same level where it was declared?

```
  const add_opted_out = (req, res) => {
          var opted_out = new Array()
          axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            parseString(res.data, (err, result) => {
            opted_out.push('a')
            // prints members
            console.log(opted_out)
            })
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(`error occured: ${err}`)
          })
          // prints nothing
          console.log(opted_out)
```

Why is this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

The code to populate `opted_out` is asynchronous. Your `console.log` that prints nothing actually executes BEFORE `opted_out` is populated.

Your function within the `.then` call is executed when the server responds to your request.

Comment: How can I use res.render then, if I need to use it within a callback function?

Comment: There should be no problem using `res.render` within a `.then` callback. A potential issue with your current setup is you have two variables called `res`. You should rename one of them.